# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete with Tagit

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the [Tagit](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) plugin to work with a jQuery Autocomplete field I have.

The autocomplete field was pulling from a remote data source to get tags from wordpress. The auto complete on its own does this fine, as you type it brings up suggestions for keywords.

I thought installing Tagit would just take the same attributes as the jQuery UI plugin, and therefore still suggest keywords via AJAX.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

The jQuery UI code I had originally is:

```
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}

function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$('.sub-category-input').change(function() {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});

$('.sub-category-input')
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
     })
    .autocomplete({
        _resizeMenu: function() {
            this.menu.element.outerWidth(300);
        },
        source: function( request, response ) {
             $('.searching').show();
             $.getJSON( "/wp-content/themes/woa-2014/sub-cats.php", {
                 term: extractLast( request.term )
             }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
             // custom minLength
             var term = extractLast( this.value );
             if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                 return false;
             }
        },
        focus: function() {
             // prevent value inserted on focus
             return false;
        },
        response: function( event, ui ) {
              $('.searching').hide();
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              $("#what").val(terms.join( ", " ));

              return false;
        },
    });
```

And the code for Tagit is simply:

```
$(".sub-category-input").tagit({
     removeConfirmation: true,
     allowSpaces: true
 });
```

Comment: So is the tagit not tagging after you press enter for autocomplete selected item? Is it so? Also, it would be better to get a JSfiddle for this...

Comment: Tagit is tagging properly, my issue is the autocomplete from the original jQuery UI input. Which doesn't work through the Tagit input. I've created a fiddle, but the autocomplete doesn't work at all in it because it doesn't have access to the file I think. http://jsfiddle.net/s2hyQ/

Comment: So what you want is that when you are typing in tagit input, autocomplete should complete it rather than the autocomplete input which you have bound to? Thus, autocomplete and tagit should work on same input, is it?

Comment: I suppose you taking tag-it in wrong manner. It gives you option for adding autocomplete it using `availableTags` option. Take a look at its code. See here: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html. Look at the single input field example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: It looks like that example uses an array for the autocomplete, I need it to AJAX the autocomplete list from a php file.

Comment: You can always return AJAX data in the `availableTags` option like `$("#selector").tagit({availableTags: function(){$.getJSON(...)}});`